# Visual Studio 2015. AXML. Doesn't work intellisence inside view with warning

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, intellisense, android-xml

This is Xamarin android application. When I write `AXML` when there are no warnings `intellisence` works fine. Bnt when I write for example `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` tag then warning appears that element isn't declared (but application works) and `intellisense` stop working inside this tag.
How to fix it?